# Laravel 5.4 Destroy POST function is going wrong

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a news thread on `laravel 5.4`. My problem is that whenever a user want to delete a post, if there is a post that has the same `id` as him, it will delete it instead of the post I originally wanted to destroy.
But if there is isn't, he can delete his post without a problem. For example, my user has an id `4` and want to delete his post which has an id of `12`. The first time I click on my delete link, it will delete the post with the `id` of `4`. When this one doesn't exist anymore, he can destroy the post with the `id` of `12`.

The function in the controller

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\StartUpPost  $startUpPost
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(StartUpPost $startUpPost)
{
    $post = StartUpPost::find($startUpPost);
    $post->delete();

    return redirect('startup/home') -> with('success', 'Post deleted !');
}
```

The route

```
Route::get('/StartUpPost/{startUpPost}/delete',[
    'uses' => 'StartUpPostController@destroy',
    'as'=>'startUpPost.delete'
]);
```

The link in HTML

```
<a href="{{route('startUpPost.delete', ['startUpPost' => $startuppost->id])}}">Delete</a>
```

The model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StartUpPost extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'start_up_posts';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'content','startup_id','image',
    ];

    public function startup() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Startup');
    }

    public function startUpComments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StartUpComment');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller function should be like this: (no need to search for the item again, you already have it with this in your fucntion parameters `StartUpPost $startUpPost`)

```
public function destroy(StartUpPost $startUpPost)
{
    $startUpPost->delete();
    return redirect('startup/home') -> with('success', 'Post deleted !');
}
```

Check the button before you click it, the mistake must be in your action link to delete the post, check how you load each button

You have `$startuppost->id` . so which post is it? I guess it takes the first one. The problem might be in the query you select the `$startuppost` before deleting it

Comment: I deleted $post = StartUpPost::find($startUpPost); and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot !